# Maxlength validation stopping me from writing more than the maxlength in mvc6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I'm following an asp.net core course on Pluralsight(this one specifically https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspnetcore-mvc-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web/table-of-contents), where we develop a full web app, currently, on the validation chapter of a contact form, the issue I'm having is that I have a textarea, where whenever it's max length is surpassed you should still be able to write in it but get an error, and when you delete up to the max length the error should disappear, but in my case I can't write anything more than the max length, thus making the validation error not appear at all.

contact.cshtml

```
@model ContactViewModel;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact us";


}
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
    <label asp-for="Name">Your name:</label>
    <br />
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    <br />
    <label asp-for="Email">Email:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="email" asp-for="Email" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
    <br />
    <label asp-for="Subject">Subject:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" asp-for="Subject" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Subject"></span>
    <br />
    <label asp-for="Message">Message:</label>
    <br />
    <textarea rows="4" asp-for="Message"></textarea>
    <span asp-validation-for="Message"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

and here is my viewmodel file
ContactViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DutchTreat.ViewModels
{
    public class ContactViewModel
    {   
        [Required]
        [MinLength(5,ErrorMessage ="Too short!")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10,ErrorMessage ="Too long!")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is a [snippet showing how every other error works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lGrh.png)

I tried using StringLength instead of MaxLength, I googled around a bit but couldn't find an answer
Is there something I'm missing? If you need additional code I can provide it

Comment: Hi @Gael123123, as Harkiratsingh said, the issue relates the `<textarea>` maxlength Attribute, it will prevent user to enter values into the `textarea` element if it is over the max length. If you want to let user enters a value which over the max length, you could consider use [remote validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#remote-attribute) or create a [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-attributes) to validte the property.

Comment: Please upvote this answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how MaxLength and StringLength data annotations are supposed to work. If you carefully inspect the html generated, it will add maxlength attribute to your message textarea. An alternative to your requirement could be manually adding maxlength to some greater value that you like.

```
<textarea rows="4" asp-for="Message" maxlength="100">
```